# Remove Index, column name and "dtype" from print output in python (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataset in python using pandas
When i perform a task and print, the output comes with some unneccesary lines like

1. index of the row
2. name of the column
3. "dtype":object

I don't want these there. for example;

I have this code to extract the country with highest cases

```
tmax= df_covid["totcases"].max()
tmin = df_covid["totcases"].min()
dfMax=df_covid.loc[df_covid['totcases'] == tmax, 'Country/Region']
dfMin=df_covid.loc[df_covid['totcases'] == tmin, 'Country/Region']

print(f"The country with the highest number of total cases is: {dfMax} with {tmax} total cases")
```

The output :

```
The country with the highest number of total cases is: 0    USA
Name: Country/Region, dtype: object with 5032179 total cases
```

My Desired Output

```
The country with the highest number of total cases is: USA with 5032179 total cases
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df_covid.loc` in your case (when specifying boolean array for row label and single label for column) will return `pd.Series` object, so you would need to access the result value directly through `values` attribute:

```
tmax = df_covid["totcases"].max()
tmin = df_covid["totcases"].min()
dfMax = df_covid.loc[df_covid['totcases'] == tmax, 'Country/Region'].values[0]
dfMin = df_covid.loc[df_covid['totcases'] == tmin, 'Country/Region'].values[0]

print(f"The country with the highest number of total cases is: {dfMax} with {tmax} total cases")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmax= df_covid["totcases"].max()
tmin = df_covid["totcases"].min()
dfMax=df_covid.loc[df_covid['totcases'] == tmax, 'Country/Region']
dfMin=df_covid.loc[df_covid['totcases'] == tmin, 'Country/Region']

print(f"The country with the highest number of total cases is: {dfMax.iloc[0].values} with {tmax} total cases")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).